# What's the biggest RAM module that I can use according to dmidecode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ram, dmidecode

I wonder if this `dmidecode` output suggests that one can put 2x16GB or 2x32GB?

I have seen that in different version of `dmidecode` information about total system maximum capacity and maximum module capacity was separated, but not in this one. Also, I haven't seen anything useful in manpages.

```
# dmidecode 3.1
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.1.1 present.

Handle 0x003E, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 32 GB
    Error Information Handle: Not Provided
    Number Of Devices: 2
```

Comment: The amount stated by `Maximum Capacity` should be the amount of potentially configurable RAM in total, all devices (channels aka RAM slots) combined. In this instance, 2x16GB would be supported, 1x32GB would be supported (but would not be utilizing dual channeling) and 2x32GB would not be supported. I have heard or read something about `dmidecode` not always being reliable, but I haven't seen that myself.

Answer (score 0):

I'd consult with the motherboard documentation and CPU specs instead. dmidecode doesn't often provide the true information about your hardware capabilities.